# How to deserialize JSON with C#?

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have the simple JSON:

```
[
  {
    "new_as_cod": "0010955",
    "as_nome": "NAME",
    "as_cpf": "1212121212",
    "as_email": "IM@UOL.COM.BR",
    "as_cep": "88.025-200",
    "igr_nome": "1\u00aa IGREJA BATISTA - FLORIANOPOLIS",
    "id": "2781",
    "valor": "50.00",
    "pg_tipo_id": "CC",
    "status": "Ativo",
    "idstatus": "1"
  }
]
```

... and a C# class generated from [here](http://json2csharp.com/):

```
 public class RootObject
    {
        public string new_as_cod { get; set; }
        public string as_nome { get; set; }
        public string as_cpf { get; set; }
        public string as_email { get; set; }
        public string as_cep { get; set; }
        public string igr_nome { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string valor { get; set; }
        public string pg_tipo_id { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string idstatus { get; set; }
    }
```

I have tried this:

```
RootObject data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(stringdate);
```

But I get the error:

[image: error]

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[{ "new_as_cod": "0010955", "as_nome": "NAME", "as_cpf": "1212121212", "as_email": "IM@UOL.COM.BR", "as_cep": "88.025-200", "igr_nome": "1\u00aa IGREJA BATISTA - FLORIANOPOLIS", "id": "2781", "valor": "50.00", "pg_tipo_id": "CC", "status": "Ativo", "idstatus": "1" }]
```

If it has `[]` this is a collection.

Try this.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(stringdate);
```

Comment: RootObject data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(stringdate);  Does not work

Comment: List<RootObject> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(stringdate);

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this JSON is a collection, so the variable needs to be list too.

```
List<RootObject> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(stringdate);
```